# Is there a way to deserialize a Java Collection so that it is mutable object (ie not Arrays$ArrayList)?

Tags: java, jpa, serializable

I'm using JPA to serialize/deserialize objects into a database.  Some of the fields for these objects are Collections.

The object backing these Collections are of type Arrays$ArrayList which is immutable.  Is there a way to deserialize them into an object of my choice?  Perhaps something like a standard ArrayList which can be modified?

Here is a snippet of my code:

**SavedSearch.java**

```
//The entity that I'm persisting using JPA

@Entity
@Table(name = "SAVED_SEARCH")
@XmlRootElement
public class SavedSearch implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "SEARCH_NAME")
    private String searchName;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "SEARCH")
    private Search search;  // The object that is being serialized by JPA

...
}
```

**Search.java**

```
public class Search implements Serializable {

    private Collection<String> labels; // This field, when deserialized,
                                       // contains an Arrays$ArrayList

...
}
```

Comment: Could you please share some code so that we may know how you are getting `Arrays$ ArrayList` ?

Comment: @SanjeevSaha Done!

Comment: You can always create a new `ArrayList` via the copy constructor: `new ArrayList<>(myUnmodifiableList)`. Now you have the same data in a modifiable list.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Well, I was trying to avoid having to manually rewrap all of these Lists, especially since I have several types of these "SavedSearch" entity classes that each contain quite a few of these Collections.

Comment: Why do you want to modify the original collections in your client code? As long as the type of these objects is `Collection`, you can't really assume that they are modifiable (or even that they are `List` implementations).

Comment: @MickMnemonic I'm using these objects and binding them to JSF components.  JSF does not like it when you assign immutable Collections to these components (spams the server logs with exceptions)

Comment: OK. Did you try changing the type of the field(s) to `List<String>` instead? You can probably also control the collection implementations Hibernate is using by tweaking the collection mapping configuration.